# Using simplexml_load_file() php, XML RSS's title for JP character error

Tags: php, xml

PHP Version: 7.4.30

I use simplexml_load_file php function,

```
$rss = simplexml_load_file($url, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
```

xml rss file[sample] :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><rss version="2.0"
xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/">
<channel>
<title>AAA</title>
<link>https://aaa.com</link>
<description>description</description>
<item>
    <title>PRODUCTS EXPO 2022 in 神戸 ダイジェスト</title>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>ˆ
```

output title[$rss->channel->item[0]->title] : **PRODUCTS EXPO 2022 in ç¥žæˆ¸ ãƒ€ã‚¤ã‚¸ã‚§ã‚¹ãƒ**ˆ

How to get title : **PRODUCTS EXPO 2022 in 神戸 ダイジェスト**

Comment: Can't replicate the problem; see https://3v4l.org/rDlb3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change this line for xml rss JP character to correct.
All fine.

```
$rss = simplexml_load_file($rsses[$i]['url'], 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
```

to

```
$feed = file_get_contents($rsses[$i]['url']);
$rss = simplexml_load_string($feed);
```

Comment: This would remove the namespace prefix `media` from the some tags in XML string. However your example XML has no elements with this prefix and here are no definitions for it.

Comment: right! I don't notice this point. thanks. I remove this line. All ok.`$feed = str_replace('<media:', '<', $feed);`

Comment: The problem might be the content type header in the HTTP response. If you use the stream wrapper (with `simplexml_load_file()`) it might be used to define the encoding. If you fetch it separately and then use `simplexml_load_string()` it will not. So if the content type header contains no or an invalid `charset` it can affect the parsing.